# How do i link SDL and GL in monodevelop (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, monodevelop

I am trying compile a simple program using openGL and SDL but I can't seem to link the library in monodevelop
I tried following [This guide](http://monodevelop.com/documentation/creating_c_and_cpp_projects) but neither SDL nor GL are on the packages list

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the [`Tao Framework`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/?source=dlp) and add the SDL and OpenGL dlls to the project references.

See [here](http://www.sdltutorials.com/settings-up-monodevelop-to-run-tao) for more details.